# XMLHttpRequest gives Invalid state when using Last.fm API

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, last.fm

I'm trying to integrate scrobble support into Ubuntu Touch's music app, but I have some difficulty since I can't seem to get the session key working.

In request() I get "Error: Invalid state" on row 53. It seems like last.fms API doesnt answer correctly, nor has the correct state, but I'm new to XMLHttpRequest, so I'm not sure what's the matter.

Code: http://pastebin.com/Aa6DVUA1

Comment: What is the value of xhr.status at line 53?

Comment: I dont get any, only "Invalid state"

Comment: Hmm, and can you post the full request you performed? (URL, headers, etc.)

Comment: It is really just a URL that is called. All the code for the request is there, but I added a complete URL of similar artists in this one: http://pastebin.com/H99h3eeY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing `encodeURIComponent` with the complete URL instead of the individual query arguments, thus resulting in something like `https%3A%2F%2Fws.audioscrobbler.com%2F2.0%2F%3Fmethod%3Dartist.getsimilar%26artist%3DKiss...` which is clearly not a valid URL. For an example see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Secondly, your usage of XMLHttpRequest is wrong, XHR operates asynchronously but you never define a callback function for your request. Querying `xhr.readyState` and `xhr.status` immediately after invoking `send()` will be executed before the request actually finishes. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for how to use XHR.

PS: Why not use one of the existing API wrappers for JavaScript, i.e. http://lastfm.felixbruns.de/javascript-last.fm-api/ or at least jQuery to handle the XHR?

PPS: Your authentication request will not work, as you are required to submit the arguments in the post body as opposed to the query string, see [this forum post](http://www.last.fm/group/Last.fm+Web+Services/forum/21604/_/2207309) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried quite many things - as well as sending a body text, but I do have some difficulty in understanding Last.fm's API instructions. This will perhaps help me a bit.

PS. Existing API wrapper: "Scrobbling is not yet supported.". Thats why.